# variable returns null outside asynctask android .null pointer exception

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

im trying to connect my app to get info from data base query is executed write and variables are place .but when it terminates from fn doinbackground i find  variable having variable is null which close whole program. i noticed that when in return result from try block in doinbackgroundfn it then jumps to return at end of fn .and then app stop .
this is the code of main 
Bur how query is executed after and printed making adapter ?
main code

```html
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class choose_buffet_items extends AppCompatActivity {
    String []categouries;
    ArrayList<buffetcategories> buff_list = new ArrayList<buffetcategories>();
    buffetcatadapter itemsAdapter;

    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT=2000;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    private boolean loggedIn = false;
    String type;
    String result;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_buffet_items);

        new JSONParse().execute();

            itemsAdapter = new buffetcatadapter(this, buff_list);
             itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_buffet);
            listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    String s =(String)adapter.getItem(i);
                    if(s.equals("Drinks"))
                    {
                        Intent numbersIntent = new Intent(choose_buffet_items.this, buffet_drinks.class);
                        startActivity(numbersIntent);
                    }
                    else if(s.equals("Cakes"))
                    {
                        Intent numbersIntent = new Intent(choose_buffet_items.this, buffet_cake.class);
                        startActivity(numbersIntent);
                    }
                    else if(s.equals("Appetizers"))
                    {
                        Intent numbersIntent = new Intent(choose_buffet_items.this,buffet_appetizers.class);
                        startActivity(numbersIntent);
                    }
                    else {Intent numbersIntent = new Intent(choose_buffet_items.this, buffet_lunch.class);
                        startActivity(numbersIntent);}

                }
            });


            listView.setAdapter(adapter);



    }
    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(choose_buffet_items.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Upadting Data");
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(choose_buffet_items.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();


        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {



                String login_URL = "http://2f179dfb.ngrok.io/getcat.php";
                try {

                    //Fetching the boolean value form sharedpreferences


                    URL url = new URL(login_URL);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                    result = "";
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result += line;
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                    Log.e("RESULT", result);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                    JSONArray result1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
                    //categouries=new String[result1.length()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < result1.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = result1.getJSONObject(i);
                        String category = c.getString("buffCategory");
                        buff_list.add(new buffetcategories(category));


                    }

                    return result;


                }
                catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;
            }




        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
               itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               pDialog.dismiss();
            alertDialog.setMessage("hello");
            alertDialog.show();




        }
    }


}
```

this is code of adapter

```html
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by extra on 25/12/2016.
 */
public class buffetcatadapter  extends ArrayAdapter<buffetcategories> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<buffetcategories> items;
    public buffetcatadapter(Activity context, ArrayList<buffetcategories> buffitems) {
        // Here, we initialize the ArrayAdapter's internal storage for the context and the list.
        // the second argument is used when the ArrayAdapter is populating a single TextView.
        // Because this is a custom adapter for two TextViews and an ImageView, the adapter is not
        // going to use this second argument, so it can be any value. Here, we used 0.
        super(context, 0,buffitems);
        this.context=context;
        this.items=buffitems;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.listviewbuffetcat, parent, false);

        }

        // Get the {@link AndroidFlavor} object located at this position in the list
        final buffetcategories currentAndroidFlavor = getItem(position);

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_name
        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.categouries);

        // Get the version name from the current AndroidFlavor object and
        // set this text on the name TextView
        nameTextView.setText(currentAndroidFlavor.getCategouries());
        Log.e("hhhh", nameTextView.getText().toString());

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_number
        ;
        // Return the whole list item layout (containing 2 TextViews and an ImageView)
        // so that it can be shown in the ListView
        return listItemView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(items == null)
            return 0;
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public buffetcategories getItem(int i) {
        return items.get(i);
    }
}
```

xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/list_item_height"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="#bbe0f7">
    <ListView

        android:id="@+id/listView_buffet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="88dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/categouries"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="name"


        />

</LinearLayout>
```

log cat

```html
com.rematchka.weddinghall E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.rematchka.weddinghall, PID: 27828
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rematchka.weddinghall/com.rematchka.weddinghall.choose_buffet_items}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.rematchka.weddinghall.choose_buffet_items.onCreate(choose_buffet_items.java:58)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
12-25 02:33:15.908 27828-29079/com.rematchka.weddinghall E/RESULT: {"result":[{"buffCategory":"Drinks"},{"buffCategory":"Cakes"},{"buffCategory":"Appetizers"},{"buffCategory":"Lunch"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting a NullPointerException is because by the time you call `listView.setAdapter(adapter);`, you have not initialized `adapter`. Also, `String s =(String)adapter.getItem(i);` will probably give you a similar exception. Did you mean to write `itemsAdapter` instead?

Comment: Yes I meant item adapter. But I still get same error

Comment: It returns null in listview listview=(listview) findviewbyid (R.I'd. Listview_buffet)